# Maximum Response Size in GraphQL API?

Tags: query, craft-pro, queries, graphql, api

hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

I'm trying to query my client's API with the Graphiql interface. My use case requires me to extract quite a lot of data from their system but the response seems to be bombing out with an

```
{
  "error": "A server error occurred."
}
```

once I get to a certain amount of objects in the response array. Reason I suspect this, despite the unhelpful error message is that I have played with adding limits to the query. So for example the query

```
query Query {
  entries(limit: 7000) {
    title 
    dateUpdated
    dateCreated
  }
}
```

will return an object containing an array if 7000 of the entries that I'm looking for (desired outcome). However, if I run

```
query Query {
  entries(limit: 9000) {
    title 
    dateUpdated
    dateCreated
  }
}
```

I'll get the error described above. Is there an upper limit on the response size that I'm missing in the documentation? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: My guess is you're hitting an environmental limitation (i.e. php.ini's `memory_limit` or `max_execution_time` setting, for example). Try checking Craft's and the web server's error logs to see if the underlying error for that "internal server error" message.

Comment: @BradBell thanks :)